# What does it mean for a distribution to be analytic and how do we analytically continue it?

Tags: complex-analysis, distribution-theory, analytic-functions, analyticity, analytic-continuation

Let $T \in S'(\mathbb{R}^n$) be a tempered distribution. I've seen a few resources (such as the first sentence of [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_function)) refer to distributions being analytic or how one can analytically continue distributions. I'm familiar with the definitions for ordinary complex functions but not for distributions. Unfortunately the Wikipedia references a textbook that I do not have access to and I could not find a formal definition on the web.

How does one define analyticity for distributions and what does it mean to analytically continue a distribution? Also I've taken the distributions to be tempered as that's commonly done, but why is this required? Could we instead take a more general type of distribution, for example $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: Are you sure you’re talking about a fixed distribution $T$? Typically, one has a family of (tempered) distributions $T_{\zeta}$ as $\zeta$ varies in some open set $U\subset\Bbb{C}^n$. Then, analyticity of $\zeta\mapsto T_{\zeta}$ typically means we require that for each test function $\phi$ (Schwartz or compactly supported, depending on situation) such that $\zeta\mapsto \langle T_{\zeta},\phi\rangle$ is an analytic function $U\to\Bbb{C}$ in the usual sense.

Comment: @peek-a-boo In general, is $\zeta$ used just for indexing $T_\zeta$ or is it also used in defining $T_\zeta$? I think your definition is in line with one I found after posting this question, which is  $T(f)$ is said to be entire analytic if the function $$z \mapsto T\Big( \sum_{i=1}^n z_i f_i\Big)$$ is analytic for every set of test functions $\{f_i\}$ and any complex number $z \equiv (z_1, \ldots, z_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo The second place I saw a distribution being referred to as analytic is in Reed & Simon volume II where they give the theorem "A tempered distribution $T$ has compact support if and only if $\hat{T}$ has an analytic continuation to an entire analytic function of $n$ variables $\hat{T}(\zeta)$ that satisfies $$|\hat{T}(\zeta)| \leq C(1 + |\zeta|)^n e^{R|Im(\zeta)|}$$ for all $\zeta \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and some constants $C, n, R$".

Comment: @peek-a-boo They define $\hat{T}(k)$ for any tempered distribution $T$ with compact support and a Schwartz function $\psi$ that is identically one on a neighborhood of the support of $T$ as $$\hat{T}(k) = (2\pi)^{-n/2}T\big(\psi e^{ik \cdot x}\big).$$ This definition seems to be different than the first one since the distribution is now fixed.

Comment: For compactly supported distributions, their Fourier transform is a (“slowly-increasing“) $C^{\infty}$ function, so $\hat{T}$ there is about as nice can be. That theorem is saying that the a-priori tempered distribution can in fact be identified with a function that has an entire analytic extension and this extension satisfies such and such growth condition. Oh and Reed-Simon also have a discussion of the Wightman axioms so…

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see, so when we speak of a tempered distribution being analytic or analytically continuing a (compactly supported) tempered distribution we really are referring to the $C^\infty$ function $\hat{T}(k)$ it induces? I am currently working through Reed and Simon's book and have not yet gotten to the Wightman axiom section yet.

Comment: In the case of compactly supported $T$, analyticity of the tempered distribution $\hat{T}$ refers to the analyticity of the analyticity of the underlying $C^{\infty}$ function which represents $\hat{T}$, yes.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see, so does this definition have anything to do with the map $z \mapsto T\Big( \sum_{i=1}^n z_i f_i\Big)$ defined in an earlier comment or are they two separate ideas?

Comment: they’re different things

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you for all your help!